# Java: Accept input as string or int

Tags: java, class, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a simple even or odd program. I want it to keep running until the user enters in 'q'. But I am having trouble accepting 'q' as a String.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class EvenOrOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to my program that checks if a number is even or odd.");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Please type number in a number ['q' to quit]: ");

            int number;
            String quit;
            try {
                number = myScanner.nextInt();
            } finally {
                quit = myScanner.nextLine();
            }

            if (quit.equals("q")) {
                break;
            } else if (number % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " is Even.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(number + " is Odd.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program works fine when I enter numbers, but when I enter 'q', the console throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at EvenOrOdd.main(EvenOrOdd.java:19)
```

I know this may be easy for many of you, but I have just picked up a java book and am trying to finish the task. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Side note: Don't compare Strings with `==`, use `.equals` instead.

Comment: Okay, I will change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like this and  i found that a boolean is better for a loop in this case instead of while(true) and break:

```
public class EvenOrOdd {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out
            .println("Welcome to my program that checks if a number is even or odd.");
    boolean enterLoop = true;
    while (enterLoop) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please type number in a number ['q' to quit]: ");

        String scannerinput = myScanner.nextLine();
        if (scannerinput.equals("q")) {
            enterLoop = false;
        } else {
            checkNumber(scannerinput);
        }

    }
}

private static void checkNumber(String scannerinput) {
    try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(scannerinput);
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(number + " is Even.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " is Odd.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No Number!");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Take a String from Scanner, check if is 'q' and if not, convert it to int and then check even or odd.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to my program that checks if a number is even or odd.");

    while (true) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please type number in a number ['q' to quit]: ");

        String inText = myScanner.next();

        if (inText.equals("q")){
            break;
        }
        int number = Integer.valueOf(inText);
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(number + " is Even.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " is Odd.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class EvenOrOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to my program that checks if a number is even or odd.");

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("\nPlease type number in a number ['q' to quit]: ");
            String input = scanner.next();
            if (input.equals("q")) {
                break;
            } else {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.print(number + " is ");
                System.out.print(number%2 == 0 ? "Even." : "Odd.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That'll do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `myScanner.nextInt()`, just use `myScanner.next()` to get a `String`. Then if it is not "q", use `Integer.valueOf(inputString)` to get the `int` and check it for even/odd.

```
while (true) {
    String input = myScanner.next();
    if ("q".equals(input)) {
        break;
    } else {
        int number = Integer.valueOf(input);
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(number + " is Even.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " is Odd.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the program is expecting a input of int-type, basically the program outputs: Please type number in a number ['q' to quit], and after that it will reach the `myScanner.nextInt();` line and will be waiting for a input, and since "q" is not a integer it will throw an exception.

A quick solution would be to use `myScanner.nextLine()` and then convert the string into a integer unless it is equal to 'q'. Something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenOrOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to my program that checks if a number is even or odd.");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Please type number in a number ['q' to quit]: ");

            String string = myScanner.nextLine();
            int number = 0;

            if (string.equals("q")) {
                myScanner.close(); // Close the scanner.
                break;
            } else if ((number = toInteger(string)) == -1){  // Is the string a number, less than Integer.MAX_VALUE and greater than Integer.MIN_VALUE?
                System.out.printf("%s is not a valid integer!%n",string);
            } else if (number % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " is Even.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(number + " is Odd.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static int toInteger(String str){
        try{
            return Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(str));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, always close the scanner, otherwise a resource leak may occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Check code note for more details.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class EvenOrOdd {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to my program that checks if a number is even or odd.");

    String input=null;
    int number;
    boolean flag=true;  // loop flag
    do {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please type number in a number ['q' to quit]: ");

        // Take user input as String
        input=myScanner.nextLine();


        try 
        {
            // convert the string value to integer value
            number = Integer.parseInt(input);

            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(number + " is Even.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(number + " is Odd.");
            }
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
        {
           // control goes here if input is not integer value
            if(input.equals("q"))   // exist option
                flag=false;
            else    // invalid input
                System.out.println("Invalid input, Please enter integer value or (q) to exist");


        }


    } while (flag);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your method flow, you are actually trying to pass and intger validation for a string so first take the input as `String` and check whether it is your quit character **q** then if it is not try to parse the string to and `int` primitive with `Integer.parseInt(input)` and test if it is Odd or Even. 
If the process fails assuming it is neither a **q** nor a number (any other character), then a message will be prompted for user telling him to use a valid number or "q" to quit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class EvenOrOdd {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Welcome to my program that checks if a number is even or odd.");

  while (true) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please type number in a number ['q' to quit]: ");

    int number;
    String input = myScanner.next();
    if (input.equals("q")) {
      break;
    } else {
      try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
           System.out.println(number + " is Even.");
        } else {
           System.out.println(number + " is Odd.");
        }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
           System.out.println("Enter valid number or \"q\" to quit!");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```